# Object { msg: "field required", type: "value_error.missing", loc: […] } even when parameters where in body

Tags: javascript, post, fastapi, missing-data

value_error.missing even when parameters are present in body
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

After googling almost everything there is and not finding the answer for my problem for few hours, I finally understood what was the problem.

The problem for me was that I was requesting strings directly as arguments to the functions and FastApi was therefore expecting one string -> query string.

Instead, I was supposed to request a model which has two strings

```
@app.post("/enter/")
def enter(ANNFilePath: str, ECGFilePath: str)
```

```
class Item(BaseModel):
    ANNFilePath: str
    ECGFilePath: str

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True

@app.post("/enter/")
def enter(item: Item)
```

Comment: It's important to note that the error message tells you this: `"loc": "query"` tells you that it expected the values to be in the query string and not in the body.

Comment: Hmm. what does this say about the "ANNFilePath" that's also in the `loc` list, though?